# How do I use Entity Framework in a CLR stored procedure?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I am looking forward to move all the logic (which is implemented as manipulating Entity Framework 4 objects) to a server side. It looks going to be simple (thanks to the application structure) and beneficial (as all I have is one oldy laptop as a client and one tough server which runs SQL Server 2008, and building a separate service for the logic can just introduce more latency if compared to doing it inside the database).

So how do I correctly use Entities Framework inside a CLR stored procedure and make it using a host-server-provided SqlContext?

Suddenly I couldn't find any examples in the Web. Looks stragne that none has yet dine this. Does it mean that the task is ridiculous and I definitely should not do that? It won't be very convenient to use T-SQL and access tables directly instead of EF classes because my model makes heavy use of inheritance and has a very complex table-per-type structure of lots of very simple tables.

Comment: "none has yet done this" ...should ring some bells. This is not the way CLR stored procedures are supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Visual Studio wouldn't even let you add the file or project type. (That's too bad, I wanted to do that also to process some really complex logic.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot - at least not at this time. The CLR contained in SQL Server 2005 through 2008 R2 is the .NET 2.0 CLR - and Entity Framework 4 requires the .NET 4 framework.

So for now, when doing stuff inside a SQL-CLR method, you're limited to straight ADO.NET 2.0 only.

The bigger question then remains: why on earth would you want to use EF4 inside a SQL-CLR function? Those are intended to be stored proc, user-defined functions, user-defined aggregates - but certainly not full-blown database apps, really...

Answer (score 2):

Some of us are not that keen to maintain database schema metadata in two or more places. EF is great to do this, but if one wants to employ the performance benefits of SQL-CLR the schema has to be defined in its context. Which at the moment means a custom metadata codes in SQL-CLR assembly that generates DDL to define a database and import it to EF.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that with SQL Server 2008 R2 or greater you can, it uses .NET ver. 4.0. See [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dohollan/archive/2010/07/08/sql-server-2008-r2-sqlclr-net-framework-version.aspx).

I run the following command against my SQL Server 2010 Developer Eeition:

```
select value from sys.dm_clr_properties where name = 'version'
```

and got the following output:

> v4.0.30319

Comment: This is not entirely true. First, the CLR version of SQL Server 2008 R2 is still 2.0, but it can use Framework Version 3.5.  And, just because the CLR version of SQL Server 2012, 2014, and 2016 is 4.0, that doesn't mean you can import any Framework DLL you want. It still must be a pure-MSIL library / DLL. If it is mixed then it won't import, even if it is the correct CLR version.